# Cannot read property apiRest

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, woocommerce

Tengo un problema con esta api.

**esto esta en html**

```
<div id="summary"></div>
```

**esto esta en JS**

```
var consuKey = "ck_b04aa6f288ee9a5495dee9c5db0a6b136350e005";
var consuSecr = "cs_1f98d389d0f9b47cd3200023864cf9b7cba50574";

function callurl() {
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://test.juand.org/wc-api/v2/reports/sales?',
   data:{
        filter: {period: "last_week"},
        consumer_key: consuKey,
        consumer_secret: consuSecr
    },
type: "GET",
dataType: "json"
})
.done(function(data){
JsonpCallback(data.reports)
})
.fail(function(data){
console.log("no");
})
}

function JsonpCallback(json) {
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
$('#summary').append('<b>Descripción:</b> ' + json[i].total_sales + '<br />');
$('#summary').append('<hr />');
}
}

callurl();
```

**Tengo el siguiente error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at JsonpCallback (VM2284:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM2284:60)
    at fire (VM2283 jquery-2.2.4.js:3187)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM2283 jquery-2.2.4.js:3317)
    at done (VM2283 jquery-2.2.4.js:8757)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM2283 jquery-2.2.4.js:9123)
```

la idea es que de el resultado del json ( **total_sales** )
pero aun no entiendo porque me da el error, si llamo a 
**JsonpCallback(data.reports)**
si uso

**JsonpCallback(data.sales)**

no da ningun resultado..

Me puedes ayudar a buscar una solicion, Gracias!!

pueden ver mi codigo aca

https://jsfiddle.net/JDLA1/a84v2x9w/2/

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda en el anterior problema, me ayudarias en este @kroneaux-schneider ?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, no puedes hacer una llamada a un usuario si no ha participado antes en la conversación. Si quieres llamarle la atención para que vea esta pregunta, deberás comentarle en la otra respuesta que te dio.

Comment: Hola @JuanDavid, no vi esta pregunta antes, con gusto hubiera ayudado. Si alguien ya te ayudó a resolver tu problema, marca su respuesta como correcta, así ayudas a quien tenga un problema parecido y ayudas (con puntos) a quien te ayudó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si haces un `console.log` de `data` en el `done` de tu llamada AJAX, podrás ver que ese objeto no contiene ningún array llamado "reports":

```
{
  "sales": {
    "total_sales": "157.94",
    "net_sales": "157.94",
    "average_sales": "22.56",
    "total_orders": 2,
    "total_items": 3,
    "total_tax": "0.00",
    "total_shipping": "0.00",
    "total_refunds": 0,
    "total_discount": "0.00",
    "totals_grouped_by": "day",
    "totals": {
      "2017-03-22": {
        "sales": "0.00",
        "orders": 0,
        "items": 0,
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      },
      "2017-03-23": {
        "sales": "0.00",
        "orders": 0,
        "items": 0,
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      },
      "2017-03-24": {
        "sales": "0.00",
        "orders": 0,
        "items": 0,
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      },
      "2017-03-25": {
        "sales": "0.00",
        "orders": 0,
        "items": 0,
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      },
      "2017-03-26": {
        "sales": "0.00",
        "orders": 0,
        "items": 0,
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      },
      "2017-03-27": {
        "sales": "0.00",
        "orders": 0,
        "items": 0,
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      },
      "2017-03-28": {
        "sales": "157.94",
        "orders": 2,
        "items": 3,
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "discount": "0.00",
        "customers": 0
      }
    },
    "total_customers": 0
  }
}
```

Por eso, cuando pasas `data.reports` a la función `JsonpCallback`, lo que estarás pasando es un `undefined` que no tiene la propiedad `length` (por eso recibes el error que recibes). Deberías revisar la documentación de la API que estás utilizando para comprobar que el resultado que recibes es el que esperas.

Parece que lo más aproximado a lo que buscas sería pasar `data.sales`, pero eso no es un array sino un objeto, entonces el bucle `for` de la función `JsonpCallback` tampoco funcionará.

Lo dicho, te recomiendo que revises la documentación de la API/servicio que estás usando para ver qué es lo que te va a devolver.

Comment: Gracias si, ya resolvi quite el for, y cambie el data.orders por data.sales.. mil gracias por tu explicación.  :)

Comment: @JuanDavid por favor, recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si resolvió tu problema así se cierra la pregunta. Saludos!